# Review/comment on this piece I wrote...

Tags: discussion, scope

We haven't had any on the site yet, but I was wondering what people are thinking with regard to questions that ask for help composing.

To me this falls a little bit within the realm of "help me transcribe/identify song x" but without the potential legal issues.

I'm sure we would always allow a question about a specific aspect of composition, like "How well does this phrase approximate the style of Chopin?" but what would we do about questions asking for general comments or feedback about a complete piece of original music? It's certainly the kind of thing that a university professor would do, and not something you can just Google, and it does have the potential to benefit more people than just the asker.

From a student's standpoint, it would also make the site incredible resource; that one could get feedback in composition from a crowd-sourced group of (theoretically) experts in the field without having to enroll in a master's program.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the idea that it's similar to transcription questions.  We're Stack Overflow, not Code Review.  Except for covering music instead of programming!

I agree providing this service could be valuable to some, as well.  But all questions like this, that are not general, are the definition of Too Localized.  They won't help anyone but the asker.  I don't think these cases should be allowed.  General questions about composition, as well as questions about components, effects, etc. that apply broadly to other compositions, should remain on-topic.

Comment: Also these questions could be very time-consuming and I think that's a bad thing.